# How to enter text in Jetpack compose TextField through UI tests?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-jetpack, ui-testing, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack compose I have a TextField and I'm trying to write Espresso UI tests.
I didn't find how I can enter text in the TextField, any ideas, please?

```
TextField(
    value = textState.value,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    onValueChange = {
        textState.value = it
        apiServiceCall(textState.value.text)
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences)
    ),
)

@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

@Test
fun enterTextAndMakeServiceCall() {
    ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)

    // TODO: Enter text inside the TextField
    composeTestRule.onNode(hasText(getString(R.string.result)))
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I first set the `testTag` modifier on the composable I want to test:

```
const val MY_TEXTFIELD_TAG = "myTextFieldTag"

TextField(
    value = textState.value,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().testTag(MY_TEXTFIELD_TAG),
    onValueChange = {
        textState.value = it
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences),
)
```

And then from your test you can set and check the value like this:

```
@Test
fun setAndCheckTheTextFieldValue() {
    ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
    val resultText = "result"

    // Sets the TextField value
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(MY_TEXTFIELD_TAG).performTextInput(resultText)

    // Asserts the TextField has the corresponding value
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(MY_TEXTFIELD_TAG).assert(hasText(resultText))
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Another way I use lately is to use the `contentDescription` instead.

Let's say you have a TextField with content description like this one (not using state hoisting for simplicity on this sample):

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField() {
    val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    val textFieldContentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.text_field_content_description)
    TextField(
        value = textState.value,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .semantics { contentDescription = textFieldContentDescription },
        onValueChange = {
            textState.value = it
        },
    )
}
```

The test could be something like:

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

@Test
fun setAndCheckTheTextFieldValue() {
    lateinit var textFieldContentDescription: String
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        textFieldContentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.text_field_content_description)
        MaterialTheme {
            MyTextField()
        }
    }
    val resultText = "result"

    // Sets the TextField value
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithContentDescription(textFieldContentDescription).performTextInput(resultText)

    // Asserts the TextField has the corresponding value
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithContentDescription(textFieldContentDescription).assert(hasText(resultText, ignoreCase = true))
}
```

and this way the app is more accessible as well by having content descriptions.

Comment: I don't think that adding Testing Code into the production codebase is a good idea. Instead I would test using: composeTestRule.onNodeWithText(text = "result").

Comment: but if its an input, you don't have any test "result" until you add it, which you need to know the element for in the first place.

Comment: I've updated the answer adding a sample of using `contentDescription` instead. This way you don't have to add this tag in production codebase and you don't rely on any previous set text while improving the accessibility of the code.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Failed to perform text input.
Failed to assert the following: (SetText is defined)` while executing `.performTextInput(text)`. Any idea why?

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki are you sure you are matching a TextField and not an element that wraps it or something like that? Cause that error seems to be about using .performTextInput() on something that doesn't seem to be a TextField.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set a `label` to your empty `TextField` then you can set text without the need for any test tags or content description like below:

```
TextField(
  ...
  label = "Production Text",
  ...
)
```

Test Code:

```
composeTestRule
  .onNodeWithText("Production Text", useUnmergedTree = true) 
  .onParent()
  .performTextInput("Test Text")
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo just can find by nodeText you need to search the string in `label` property

```
composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("user").performTextInput("userCred")
```

That will find that Textfield and will enter the text "userCred".

This solution only works if you don't have any other text that matches that string.

Comment: Your approach won't work if node doesn't have text. In other words if the textfield is empty